# How to open an image view from clicking on a context menu option?

Tags: java, android, image, click, android-menu

I have a context menu in my main activity that opens when an item is selected or clicked. When the user clicks one of the strings listed in the context menu, how can I get an image to appear? I only have the context menu written in Java and not xml. Here is the code.

```
package com.carouseldemo.main;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.carouseldemo.controls.Carousel;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemClickListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselAdapter.OnItemSelectedListener;
import com.carouseldemo.controls.CarouselItem;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // Just prepare ourself for unexpected arguments...
    if (menuInfo == null) {
        return;
    }
    if (!(menuInfo instanceof AdapterContextMenuInfo)) {
        return;
    }
    AdapterContextMenuInfo mi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
    switch (mi.position) {
    case 0:
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 1:
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 2:
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 3:
        menu.add("mouse menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 4:
        menu.add("panda menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    case 5:
        menu.add("rabbit menu");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        menu.add("Product 1");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
}
```

When one of the "Product 1" from menu.add is clicked, how can I get an image view to pop up? Any ideas on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try having :

```
menu.onClick(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick() {
    // Do Something here
    }
});
```

Also, as part of the ContextMenu, you will have the findItem(int item) which you can override and return the item of your choice.

Comment: For the //Do Something here.  What is the command to open the image? That's the thing I need help with.

Comment: Also, where do I put this in the code? It's giving me errors wherever I put it.

Comment: ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
imageView.setImage(R.drawable.sampleImage);
imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Thank you. Where would I put this code? I receive errors wherever I place it.